# How do i list all children terms of related term in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm really struggling with trying to find an answer for this and have spent 6 hours searching and messing around in views. Let me explain.

I have two taxonomy vocabularies: Catalog and Fabric.
I have a list of Fabrics in Fabric in a hierarchical structure similar to the following:

Seasonal-2010
-Company
--Fabric Designer
---Fabric Collection
----Fabric Name
Seasonal-2009
-Company
--Fabric Designer
---Fabric Collection
----Fabric Name

In the Catalog vocabulary I have catalog categories: Christmas, Spring, Summer etc.
I have related (using the Taxonomy Vocabulary Relate module), the Christmas term in Catalog with Seasonal-2010 term in Fabric.

What I am trying to do is pass in the Term ID for Christmas and display a list of all the Fabric Names in that category. So what I need to do is get TermID then get Related Terms then get Children for the related terms.

I've already made a view which outputs the Related Term, now all I need to do is get the children. In a different view I can get the immediate children (ie the company) but not their children and so on. Does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't know what exactly the answer... But you can use **node hierarchy** module. This is a very good module for the hierarchical view.Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for as that involves nodes. Had a go with taxonomy list - which i'm keeping as it is useful for Admin purposes. 
Had to hack around in the end, use two different displays and some code to transfer the result as an argument from one to another. Now works perfectly.